# VTK, ViewPlaneNormal computation gives me the opposite of my intuition

Tags: vtk

I am confused about the computation of the normal of the ViewPlane in VTK

I have this simplest example that bugs me:

```
    camera.SetPosition((0, 100, 0))
    camera.SetFocalPoint((0, 0, 0))
    camera.SetViewUp(0, 0, 1)
```

When I request:

```
    camera.GetViewPlaneNormal()
```

I get:
(-0.0, 1.0, -0.0)
which does not make sense to me, I was expecting the opposite. Can someone explain please?